# Verify if a PDF is secured/protected with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Is it possible to verify if we can copy the content of a PDF document with iTextSharp?

I have a method that copy the content of the PDF and add a new page at the end with project's information but it throw a "System.ArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password". I get this error when I do `writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: "System.ArgumentException: PdfReader not opened with owner password" - are you opening the pdf with the owners password? If not that would be your first step, if you are then that exception is misleading.

Comment: I don't have the password, I want to verify if a password is needed because a user can upload any PDF and I need to verify if I can copy this PDF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to just check the property `PdfReader.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions`.

```
PdfReader r = new PdfReader("YourFile.pdf");
if (r.IsOpenedWithFullPermissions)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: I'm using a stream from an uploaded files and when I verify on the pdfreader it break my pdf, do I need to return to position 0 on my stream or close anything so I can save my stream without any problem?

Comment: Ok that's it, I had to put position back to 0