# iText - Read Security Method from PDF file

Tags: itext

Adobe's Document Security User Guide (http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/doc_sec_user_guide_9.pdf) states (In paragraph 4.1.1) that the following options exist:
- Password security
- Public Key certificate security
- ALCRMS

Can I inspect a PDF file with iText (specifically iTextSharp 5) to determine which specific security method it uses?

I checked [checking if pdf is password protected using itextsharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298651/checking-if-pdf-is-password-protected-using-itextsharp) but I would like to discriminate between the various methods, not just determine that the document is protected.